# How to Run job operation synchronously of a Pipeline in Google Cloud Platform (apache beam)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Running a apache beam pipeline in Google Cloud Platform(dataflowRunner), there may be cases where  want to run some code only after all the other steps have finished.

here is my python code

```
  p = beam.Pipeline(options=options) 
wisgen_data = p | "wisgen job" >> ReadFromJdbc (
jdbc_url=jdbc_url,
username=username,
password=password,
driver_class_name='org.postgresql.Driver',
query="""SELECT users.id AS user_id, CONCAT(users.first_name,' ', users.last_name) AS full_name""",
table_name="users"
)
recruiter_data = p | "recruiter job" >> ReadFromJdbc(
jdbc_url=jdbc_url,
username=username,
password=password,
driver_class_name='org.postgresql.Driver',
query="""SELECT users.id AS user_id, '""",
table_name="users"
)
wisgen_data | "Convert TableRow to dict(wisgen data)" >> beam.Map(
lambda row: row._asdict()
) | "Write to BigQuery in wisgen data table" >> WriteToBigQuery(
wisgen_table,
write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
schema='user_id:INTEGER,full_name:STRING)
recruiter_data | "Convert TableRow to dict(recruiter data)" >> beam.Map(
lambda row: row._asdict())
 | "Write to BigQuery in recruiter data table" >> WriteToBigQuery(
recruiter_table,
write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
schema='user_id:INTEGER,full_name:STRING'
)
_ = (p
| "Create current timestamp" >> beam.Create([{'time': datetime.datetime.utcnow()}])
| "Write to last_sync" >> WriteToBigQuery,
last_sync_tab
schema='time:TIMESTAMP',
write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
)
```

**The pipeline runs asynchronously OR perform all job operation parallel  but I want this below job operation only runs until above all operations are finished.**

```
   _ = (p
| "Create current timestamp" >> beam.Create([{'time': datetime.datetime.utcnow()}])
| "Write to last_sync" >> WriteToBigQuery,
last_sync_tab
schema='time:TIMESTAMP',
write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I recommend you to launch the second part in a separate process : other `Dataflow` job for example and use a pipeline orchestrator like `Airflow/Composer` to sequence the 2 jobs :

```
DAG -> Launch Dataflow job 1 -> Launch Dataflow job 2
```

In this case the synchronization would be perfect.

I think it's not possible to sequence 2 sinks (multi sinks) natively with `Beam`.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no other way to run that last job operation in the same single pipeline runs at the end when all above is finished ?